# why does this code produce deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class A {
    static final int i;
    static {
        i = 128;

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("i=" + i);
            }
        };
        t.start();
        try {
           t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
public class MainTesting {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println("finish");
    }
}
```

I never get `finish` get printed and value of i.
Why is it so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You start off on thread 1 (the "main" thread), and start executing the static initializer for the `A` class.

Within that static initializer, you then start a new thread (2), which uses something within the `A` class. That means that thread 2 needs to wait until the `A` class has finished initilaizing before it will proceed, as per [section 12.4.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2):

> If the Class object for C indicates that initialization is in progress for C by some other thread, then release LC and block the current thread until informed that the in-progress initialization has completed, at which time repeat this step.

However, your static initializer for `A` waits until thread 2 has completed (by calling `join()`) before *it* completes, leading to deadlock: the static initializer can't complete until thread 2 has completed, and thread 2 can't complete until the static initializer has completed...

Upshot: don't do this :)

Comment: Please don't mind but I think you have already answered this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686333/deadlock-caused-by-thread-join-in-a-static-block

Comment: @MickJ: Yes, I tend to find it hard to remember everything I've answered in the last two months, let alone the last two years :)

Comment: I can understand. Burden of being Jon Skeet :) I like it anyway. New people like me feel more welcome when they get answers rather than angry downvotes and 'do some research before posting' comments. I like it this way +1

Answer (score 6):

Loading of classes and static blocks are implicitly synchronized This means you cannot access anything in a class in another thread while it is being initialised. In this case the initialisation is waiting for a thread which is using `A.i`.  In other words, it is waiting for the first thread to finish the static block.

Note: it doesn't use a normal lock and the thread claims to be in a Runnable state even though it is deadlocked.

```
2013-06-21 11:20:40
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode):

"Thread-0" prio=6 tid=0x000000000d55d000 nid=0x3cc4 in Object.wait() [0x000000000dbdf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at Main$1.run(Main.java:14) <- where A.i is referenced.

"main" prio=6 tid=0x00000000022df000 nid=0x3284 in Object.wait() [0x000000000257e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007d5610448> (a Main$1)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1258)
    - locked <0x00000007d5610448> (a Main$1)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1332)
    at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:19)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)
```

Comment: "static blocks are implicitly synchronized" synchronization happens on object, right? but static block might not have any object associated with it..

Comment: static blocks are associated with the `ClassName.class` object. If you do a `static synchronized ` method, this is the object you are locking.  I don't know if class loading is implemented this way or there is a lock on the class loader or some global lock.  I suspect it's JVM dependent.